# Disable Button after Getting confirmation on Button Click Java Script

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I want to take confirmation from the user to Submit the form or not.

If the user Selects yes, The Submit button should be disabled & the Text should become "Please Wait" until the server side code is executed through C#.

C# code should only be executed if the user selects Yes in the Confirmation Popup.

I have tried the Following Javascript Code:

```
function confirmSubmit(element)
    {
        if (confirm('Are you Sure?'))
        {
          
            element.disabled = true;
            element.value = 'please wait ...';           
            return true;       
    }
        else
        {
        return false;
    }  
    }
```

I have called the JS Method on Button click like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Submit" Text="Submit Time Sheet" CssClass="btn mybtn confirmbtn" Width="100%" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click"
                         OnClientClick="return confirmSubmit(this);" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                      />
```

It works till the Disable but return does not work

Comment: How you are sending information to the server? As you have `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` which will prevent the form submission (if you have a form) You need to submit the form or use your servers API to send the data to the server.

Comment: You call the function from the onclick event so it returned the answer to the event dispatch and not where you want it ( i am a c# expert but in js it works like that) try and separate it